# Overwhelmed feeling when visiting Temple

Tags: temples

Is there a reason why I get this overwhelmed feeling and want to cry when I visit the Temple?

Comment: Is it a happy feeling or a sad feeling?

Comment: Hi Alice and welcome to Buddhism.SE. We've put together some information to help you get started [here](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/i-am-a-new-user-here-at-buddhism-se-what-should-i-know-before-i-post).

Answer (score 3):

Do you like the Temple? Is it beautiful in your eyes? Judging by your response, it sounds as if it is very meaningful to you. I know that when I visit my local Zen center, entering the meditation hall causes such a reaction (along with a deep feeling of peace).

Crying is a natural human response to many situations and stimuli. [This article](http://scienceline.org/2006/10/ask-driscoll-tears/) offers a socio-biological reason for the crying response.

Interestingly, at least according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crying#Religious_views_on_crying), crying in Buddhism is considered unskillful, as it indicates clinging/attachment.